# Crear Menú como componente en Ionic 5

Tags: ionic

Estoy intentando crear un menú para mi aplicación de Ionic 5.
Esto no me funciona, sin embargo si pongo el código del menú en el app.component.html si funciona y se despliega correctamente.
He importado el menu module y el home module en el app.module, sospecho que el error tiene que ver con el routing, pero no estoy seguro.
Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda-

Para ello he generado un page llamado menu:

menu.page.html

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main" when="md">
    <ion-menu side="start" contentId="main">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="primary">
          <ion-title>Menú</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-menu-toggle autoHide="false" *ngFor="let page of pages">
            <ion-item [routerLink]="page.path" routerDirection="root" [class.active-menu]="selectedPath === page.path">
              {{page.name}}
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main" main></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

menu.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router, RouterEvent } from "@angular/router";
import { MenuService } from '../services/menu.service';

@Component({
  selector: "app-menu",
  templateUrl: "./menu.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./menu.page.scss"],
})
export class MenuPage implements OnInit { 
  pages = [];
  selectedPath = "";

  constructor(
    private router: Router,  
    private menuService: MenuService)
     {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
      this.selectedPath = event.url;
      console.log("Selected path: " + this.selectedPath);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pages = this.menuService.pages;
    console.log(this.pages);
  }
```

menu-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { MenuPage } from './menu.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MenuPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class MenuPageRoutingModule {}
```

menu.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { MenuPage } from "./menu.page";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { IonicModule } from "@ionic/angular";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'menu',
    component: MenuPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: '../home/home.module#HomePageModule'
      },
    ]
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
  declarations: [MenuPage],
})
export class MenuPageModule {}
```

En mi home page tengo lo siguiente:
home.page.html

```
 <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Header</ion-title>
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-menu-button autoHide="false"></ion-menu-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { LoginComponent } from './start/login/login.component';
import { AutoAttendanceComponent } from './start/auto-attendance/auto-attendance.component';
import { CheckTransportComponent } from './start/check-transport/check-transport.component';
import { SupervisionImplementsComponent } from './start/supervision-implements/supervision-implements.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './start/components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './start/components/footer/footer.component';

import { HomePageModule } from './home/home.module';
import { MenuPageModule } from './menu/menu.module';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AutoAttendanceComponent,
    CheckTransportComponent,
    SupervisionImplementsComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    HomePageModule,
    MenuPageModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTableModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { LoginComponent } from "./start/login/login.component";
import { AutoAttendanceComponent } from "./start/auto-attendance/auto-attendance.component";
import { CheckTransportComponent } from "./start/check-transport/check-transport.component";
import { SupervisionImplementsComponent } from "./start/supervision-implements/supervision-implements.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: LoginComponent },
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  { path: "attendance", component: AutoAttendanceComponent },
  { path: "check-transport", component: CheckTransportComponent },
  { path: "check-implements", component: SupervisionImplementsComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: <ion-router-outlet id="main"></ion-router-outlet> debe estar en el app.componente.html para que cargue tu componente menú en la ruta ''. ¿Si esta ahí?

Comment: Si lo he probado ahí tal cual tu lo pones en el ejemplo, pero tampoco funciona. Solo funciona si el menú está dentro del app.component.html, es decir, el mismo html que tengo en el menu.page.html

Comment: En tu routing agrega {path: '**', component: MenuPage} y esto @NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)], en vez de forChild ya que es la ruta el routing inicial.
y <ion-router-outlet id="main"></ion-router-outlet> en tu app.component.hml.
¿podrias subir tu app.module.ts?

Comment: @UrielManzano {path: '**', component: MenuPage} lo agrego al app-routing.module.ts o al menu-routing.module.ts? Edito la pregunta y subo el app.module.ts

Comment: perdon me equivoque va en el menu-routing.module.ts y asegurate que en app-routing.ts este RouterModule.forRoot(routes). Creo que tu problema esta en app-routing.module.ts ¿Lo podrias subir?

Comment: @UrielManzano, listo ya subí el app-routing.module.ts. En el menu-routing.module.ts es que agrego esto, correcto?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116664/discussion-between-uriel-manzano-and-esteban-varela).

Comment: Parece que todo esta bien, si localhost:puerto/menu no te muestra menu.page? si estas importando MenuPageRoutingModule en tu menu.module.ts?

Comment: @UrielManzano si abro localhost:port/menu no me aparece nada, y si está MenuPageRoutingModule en el menu.module.ts

Comment: cambia loadChildren: '../menu/menu.module#MenuPageModule' por loadChildren: () => import('./menu/menu.module').then(m => m.MenuModule(No se como se llama tu modulo menu))